# is it possible to add RTL direction for onsen ui 2?

Tags: css, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

i'm using Cardova with onsen ui v2  but i'm still wondering if its possible to add RTL direction

```
RTL
html
input[type=text]
{
 direction: rtl;
}
p,
h4{
text-align: right !important;
}
```

i tired to put this code into my app css files but isn't worked , contact appears with wrong directions on Hebrew language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onsen UI has a complicated DOM, I recommend "inspect element" each section you want; and add direction to it.

But this will change the direction of most contents in the pages

```
.page__content {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

see live [demo](https://codepen.io/miladd3/pen/OJJzrwM)